# Не работает вывод в файл c++

Tags: c++

В программе беру строку из одного файла, удаляю самые длинные слова в ней и пишу во второй файл.
Не выходит т.к. вылетает ошибка out_of_range [image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Не понимаю в чем проблема, строка не пустая, файл открыт (как я это понял - при запуске скрипта при изначальном состоянии файла все работает).
Изначально писал туда три строчки:
У попа была собака он ее любил
Она съела кусок мяса
Он ее убил.
Но когда меняю текст на другой, скрипт не работает с этой ошибкой.

```
    ifstream fout;
fout.open("F1.txt");
fstream fin;
fin.open("F2.txt");
const int lenght = 200;
char str[lenght], str_2[lenght], line_delimiter = '\0';
int i = 0, count = 0, word_lenght = 0, word_position = 0;
string line, word;
cout << "Прочитаем текст в файле\n";
while (fout.getline(str, lenght)) {
    cout << str << endl;
    count = 0;
    word_lenght = 0;
    line = "";
    for (i = 0; str[i] != line_delimiter; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' ') {
            count++;
        }else {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (word_lenght < count) {
            word_position = i - count;
            word_lenght = count;    
            line = str;
        }
        word = str[i];
    }
    if (!line.empty()) {
        line.erase(word_position, word_lenght + 1);
        if (fin.is_open())
        {
            fin << line << "\n";
        }
    }
}
cout << "\nУдалим самые длинные слова в строках\n";
while (fin.getline(str_2, lenght)) {
    cout << str_2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Поставьте точку останова на if (fin.is_open()) и fin << line << "\n"; перед возникновением ошибки и смотрите содержимое fin и line.

Comment: @Blackmeser в fin файл, в line строка, все как надо

Comment: fin.open("F2.txt", fstream::app);